# Parsing WMI AntiVirusProduct productState from \\.\root\SecurityCenter2

Tags: windows, windows-10, wmi, wmi-query

I'm trying to parse the result of `productState` from `WMI` query to `\\.\root\SecurityCenter2\` for `AntiVirusProduct`. I'm on Windows 10 1803 (10.0.17134) and 1809 (10.0.17763) (yeah, two computers, twice the troubles...). I'm using C++/CLI but could be C# or whatever, it doesn't matter... I just want to understand the result.

When my *Windows Defender* is **activated**, I get 0x00061110.

When it is **deactivated**, I get 0x00062110.

*MS* doesn't seem to give much info about the meaning of theses results.

According to [this site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6501b87e-dda4-4838-93c3-244daa355d7c/wmisecuritycenter2-productstate?forum=vblanguage), the second byte should be 0x11 for *enabled* and 0x01 for *disabled*. Since I get 0x21, what does it mean?

Also, what would it be with another antivirus product? Is there a way to understand this UINT32 number??? Actually, it is quite easy to get the name of the product (`displayName`) but I want to know if it is activated or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 10, I use [IWscProduct](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/iwscapi/nn-iwscapi-iwscproduct) interface (tested in C++ and C#, it works fine)

which returns values easy to understand ([WSC_SECURITY_PRODUCT_STATE](https://learn.microsoft.com//windows/win32/api/iwscapi/ne-iwscapi-wsc_security_product_state))

There is a C++ sample in the SDK : [Windows Security Center API sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebSecurityCenter)

Comment: Quoting: "Returns the current state of the signature data for **the** security product." Does it check/manage only Windows Defender or any active product?

Comment: There is : _WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_ANTIVIRUS  The aggregation of all antivirus products for this computer._